# Displaying text from dxf in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, dxf

I managed to import .dxf into Postgis table, and now have, among others, rows with Point geometries and values in text column (which corespodent with Label values from ACAD .dxf).

What is the best way to display these geometries in Openlayers so they look the same as in any other dxf viewer (format, size, color)? Fonts, sizes and colors are imported into postgis using sql "select *,ogr_style from entities".

The rest of the geometries (lines, polygons) are correctly displayed using HTTP protocol and GeoJSON format, but with labels missing.

Also, is there a way to import Text from .dxf into Postgis as set of lines/polygons? That would also solve the problem.